# How to get dropdown value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

```
<select class="dd01" onchange="dd01change()">
<option value="323">323</option>
<option value="525">525</option>
<option value="727">727</option>
</select>
```

js

```
function dd01change() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    alert (a);
};
```

Doesn't work. In console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much more simplest way is to use the `.change()` function that executes each time the change event is triggered.

```
$(".dd01").change(function () {

    alert(this.value);

});
```

**[Working JSFiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/gkmj94g0/)**

---

```js
$(".dd01").change(function() {

  alert(this.value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dd01" onchange="dd01change()">
  <option value="323">323</option>
  <option value="525">525</option>
  <option value="727">727</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
<select class="dd01" onchange="dd01change(this)">
<option value="323">323</option>
<option value="525">525</option>
<option value="727">727</option>
</select>

function dd01change(el) {
    var a = $(el).val();
    alert (a);
};
```

Comment: That's cool. Please accept the answer if you're OK with that.

Comment: Of course, I will, but I just need to wait 7 min. more. :)

Comment: @bonaca, do you really need jquery for this?

Comment: @nevermind, maybe not just for this code, but I need jQuery for all my other stuff.